# how to can i get values from picklist values and add them in another field

Tags: visualforce

I have two values I want to get the values from two values and want to display  the result on the third field. I tried the below code but not able to able get expected result. Please help me with this.

```
<apex:page standardController="EvaluationInformation__c" extensions="EISControllerV">
.....

    <!--Picklist (values : 1,2)-->
    <div>
        <apex:inputField id="Emp_1_1" value="{!evaluation.PE1}" styleClass="plStyle"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="sumwrapper"></apex:actionSupport>
    </div>   
    <div>
        <apex:inputField id="Emp_1_2" value="{!evaluation.PE2}" styleClass="plStyle"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="sumwrapper"></apex:actionSupport>
    </div>  
    
    <!-- SUM will be showed here-->
    <apex:outputPanel id="sumwrapper">
        <apex:outputText value="{!evaluation.PE1 + evaluation.PE2}" id="dpdresult" />      
    </apex:outputPanel>
    .....
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid tags which clearly have nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the actionsupport inside the inputfield.

```
<apex:inputField id="Emp_1_1" value="{!evaluation.PE1}" styleClass="plStyle">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="sumwrapper"/>
</apex:inputField>
```